# Resize body according to screen resolution using HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: html, css, resize, resolution, sticky-footer

I’m trying to do the following. Create a website with a static top (Header) and article area in the middle and a sticky footer with the navigation controls. My challenge is the following. I want the controls to at the bottom of the page at all time, so in case one rescale the browser / open the page at different resoullution it is only the article area that is resized …. I have not been able to solve this / or seen a page that is doing this.
I want a static header of 100px, a static footer of 150px and an article area of window.innerHeight – footer – header
I have seen a lot of page with static footers, but all for all of them you have to browse to the bottom of the screen for it so be seen. I want mine to shown in the bottom of the screen at all times. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#header{
background:yellow;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
height:100px;
width:100%;    
}

#foot{
background:yellow;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
height:150px;  
width:100%;        
}

#content{
background:orange;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
bottom:150px;
width:100%;    
}
```

In xhtml http://jsfiddle.net/DWMHr/

Comment: Thank you. 
In your solution, is there any way to set "width: 700px;" and make the block move to the center at all time. 
left: 0; makes everything move to the left .... but i do not have a center.
Any ideas ?

Comment: simply add body{width:700px;margin:0 auto;}

Comment: Thank you, but it is not totally what i'm looking for ...
Please look at [my temporary page](http://www.loeppenthien.net):
body {
  background: #534741; 
  margin:   0 auto;
  padding:  0;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:  80%;
  hight:  100%;  
 }
 
 header {
 background:  #fafafa;
 display:  block;
 position:  absolute;
 top: 0px;
 margin:   0 auto;
 width:   920px;
 color:   #333;
 height:   100px;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 }

Comment: margin:0 auto; need a width to calculate his position ! you have another error on hight -> height !

Answer (score -1):

I think your best option might be to make the article area `overflow:scroll`

Comment: And for some reason I thought that this was going to be on a phone which is why I suggested overflow:Scroll as a possible solution... so ignore my answer